# Sampling from a multivariate distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, simulation, graph-theory

Given $X = [X_1 X_2 \ldots X_n]^{\top}$ is a vector of independent bernoulli random variables and $A \in \{0, 1\}^{m \times n}$ is an arbitrary boolean matrix. Define a random variable $Y$ as
$$Y = AX$$

Does $Y$ follow any known distribution? Is there a way to uniformly sample from the distribution followed by $Y$?

Some more details:
$A$ is the incidence matrix of a graph G
$X_i$ is associated with edges of the graph G
$Y$ calculates the degree of nodes of the graph G

I am essentially interested in sampling the node degree sequences.

One Possible Solution:
Uniformly sample over $X$ and calculate $Y$. However, I am not sure whether that guarantees uniformity in the samples of $Y$. While, uniformly sampling over $X$ gives graphs proportional to their probability, that need not necessarily give rise to degree sequences proportional to their probability (assuming that the degrees achieve high probability when they are closest to their expected degrees).

---

I forgot about this question until someone upvoted it today. To give more details, I was working on the following problem at the time when I had asked this question:

In social networks, people work with graphs that are probabilistic in nature, that is, for example, every edge in the social network in the graph has a probability value associated with which usually indicates how much does a user $u_i$ influences user $u_j$.

Now, on this probabilistic graph, social network analysis requires several estimates to be done and they are often done using Monte Carlo runs. However, one can imagine these edge probabilities introducing a distribution over all possible graphs. Then, instead of doing Monte Carlo runs (which can be pretty expensive), one can try to identify a handful of good samples that one can use to estimate the desired quantities. In [this paper](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~dimitris/PAPERS/SIGMOD14-UG.pdf), the authors propose to do exactly that. However, the way they went about finding these representative samples there was no proof associated whether their samples would give an unbiased estimate or not. I wished to put their work in a more statistical footing (possibly even improving the representative samples that we can get) and was working towards a framework to establish that.

However, due to several non-technical reasons, I unfortunately could not continue the work. Regardless, I hope this short excerpt gives sufficient background for the question that I was asking.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "uniformly" sampling $Y$?  Usually when we write about "sampling" a random variable, we mean that the results we obtain are independent and in the long run reproduce the probability law governing $Y,$ which in this case will usually *not* be a uniform law.

Comment: @whuber sorry about the wording, I meant I wanted to get i.i.d samples from the distribution of Y

Comment: Maybe you could then edit in IID so the question becomes clear!